# How to use Google map styles on a My Map

Tags: google-maps, styles

I am new to playing around with the Google maps API and have what should be a simple question yet I can't find a simple answer after hours of Googling. I am a fiction writer and a hypertext project I'm writing is set in a fictionalized version of Milwaukee, WI. I want to embed a styled Google map with links to a wiki based on the fictional world.

So I can create a My Places map with markers and links:
http://trenthergenrader.com/calypsis/rivertown%20googlemap/mymap.html

And I can create a styled Google map of Milwaukee:
http://trenthergenrader.com/calypsis/rivertown%20googlemap/styled.html

But I don't see how to create a styled version of the My Places map. Everywhere I look for instructions on how to do this, it simply says to use the link and embed feature in Google maps but I don't how/where to add the styling when all I get is a long link within an iframe tag.

This has got to be possible, right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not possible. You could get the KML output of the My Map and add it as a KMLLayer on your Google Maps API site. When you're viewing the My Map, get the copy link marked "KML". Here's the KMLLayer documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers

Comment: Gah, that would explain why my searches turned up nothing. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a shot.